# Schedule And Close Tasks In Batch?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file which currently opens a file and specifies parameters for the file to run. I'd like to automate how many hours this program can run (random between x and x hours) for and automate when it should open again (will run between x time and x time). Is this possible to do with batch alone?

There will be multiple instances of the same process open so killing it by process name would not work.

I'd like the batch file to open and close the specified program keeping the input parameters daily.

Comment: Simple answer: no. A batch file is just a list of instructions to run in order; what you're asking for requires a service running in the background, scheduling the task. I'ms sure there are tools out there which can do this, but unfortunately this site doesn't allow software recommendation questions. There is a [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), but please check their help centre for what details they require before posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

Batch file alone can't do that.

Assuming you use Windows already, just make use of the [Windows Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) wich is available by default and add your batch file as task to be run.

Comment: Ok so in theory I could do part of it in batch such as sleeping random amount of time then opening the program, and the other parts to kill the program and open the batch file again with the task scheduler? That would make sense.

Comment: I would prefer to just schedule the batch file multiple times in a given period on a daily basis (for example. each minute), which can be done easily with the Windows Task Scheduler. Let the scheduler 'fire and forget', I would not run a batch file once for  'the whole day' with random sleeps.